# Does typescript allow to define a type for a lambda params?

Tags: typescript, lambda, parameters

Why it is not possible to do in ts something like this:

```
var stringArray: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"];
stringArray.map(str: string => console.log(str));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var stringArray: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"];
stringArray.map(str: string => console.log(str));
```

Actually you can, you just need to take it into brackets:

```
stringArray.map((str: string) => console.log(str));
```

but in fact you can omit type declaration, because of type inference compiler already knows that `str` is a type of `string`:

```
stringArray.map(str => console.log(str));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with brackets :). 
Yeah, sure, I understand that typescript already sense that he works with strings. In my case, I work with pure json, and i want to cast some parts of it to my custom class.

Comment: better if you create an interface for the data you get from json, if its possible of course. And you'll get type hinting for the whole json you get

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try :)